# Zoo Visitor email registration refresh

Tags: forms, zoo-visitor, registration

iv been trying to setup the email registration form for zoo-visitor when I add in all the credentials and hit submit the form just refreshes with a blank form and the error messages says 
"**The following field is required: Email**"

```
{exp:zoo_visitor:registration_form return='dashboard' class="form" error_handling='inline' error_delimiters='<span class="alert alert-error">|</span>' autologin='yes' allowed_groups='5'}

    <div class="arrow"></div>

    <input type="hidden" name="group_id" value="5">

    <div class="form-group">
        <input id="trainer_firstname" class="form-control input-lg" name="trainer_firstname" type="text" placeholder="First name" value="" />

    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input id="trainer_lastname" class="form-control input-lg" name="trainer_lastname" type="text" value="" placeholder="Last Name" />

    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input id="trainer_phone" class="form-control input-lg" name="trainer_phone" type="text" value="" placeholder="Phone" />    

    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input id="email" class="form-control input-lg" name="email" type="text" value="" placeholder="Email" />
        {error:email}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input id="password" class="form-control input-lg" name="password" type="password" value="" placeholder="Password" />
        {error:password}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input id="password_confirm" class="form-control input-lg" name="password_confirm" type="password" value="" placeholder="Confirm Password" />
    </div>

     <input class="form-submit" type="submit" value="Register" />


    {field_errors}{error}{/field_errors} 

{/exp:zoo_visitor:registration_form}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check to see if the member_email is required in your custom field groups?